# How to get effects to work one and override others

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, picturebox

Hi, I have created a picturebox which, when a an effect is selected, it will then change the image in the picture box using the color matrix.

The issues I'm having is if I choose another effect when one is selected the old effect will not disappear, instead it will just stay there and be underneath the new effect selected. The effects I'm using is sepia and greyscale for now, but can anyone help me so that once one effect is selected, the old effect is cleared rather than them just stacking up on one another.

I am using the graphics and colormatrix as well as bitmap and here is the code for my two buttons:

```
Graphics g;

private void greyscalePicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   Image img = pictureBox.Image;
   Bitmap greyscaleBitmap = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
   ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
   ColorMatrix cmImage = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
   {
      new float[] {.3f, .3f, .3f, 0, 0}, 
      new float[] {.59f, .59f, .59f, 0, 0}, 
      new float[] {.11f, .11f, .11f, 0, 0}, 
      new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
      new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
   });
   ia.SetColorMatrix(cmImage);
   g = Graphics.FromImage(greyscaleBitmap);
   g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), 0, 0,
               img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
   g.Dispose();
   pictureBox.Image = greyscaleBitmap;
}

// This is the same as the grey effect except
// the float values have been changed
private void sepiaPicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Image img = pictureBox.Image;
   Bitmap sepiaBitmap = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
   ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
   ColorMatrix cmImage = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
   {
      new float[] {.393f, .349f, .272f, 0, 0}, 
      new float[] {.769f, .686f, .534f, 0, 0}, 
      new float[] {.189f, .168f, .131f, 0, 0}, 
      new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
      new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1} 
   });
   ia.SetColorMatrix(cmImage);
   g = Graphics.FromImage(sepiaBitmap);
   g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), 0, 0,
               img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
   g.Dispose();
   pictureBox.Image = sepiaBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Try using interpunction and please format your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the original image, apply the effect on this **original** one not the current one:

```
//Your form constructor
public Form1(){
   InitializeComponent();
   originalImage = pictureBox.Image;
}
Image originalImage;
private void greyscalePicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 Image img = originalImage;// Not pictureBox.Image
 //...
}
private void sepiaPicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 Image img = originalImage;// Not pictureBox.Image
 //...
}
```

The point is whenever you want to save the current state, just update your `originalImage` to make any next effect apply **alternatively**.

Comment: I'm still a beginner so sorry if this sounds silly but with the "yourimage" are you saying that i should use this as a string or should i replace "yourimage" with the picturebox.image just that i'm a bit confused

Comment: @JamesAdegoroye how do you **initialize** the beginning Image for your `PictureBox`? You can just do the same with the variable `originalImage`, anyway you can place this code in your form constructor: `originalImage = pictureBox.Image;`

Comment: With my code i use a openfiledialog and use the filename to get the image the method is above this code , haha i'm just sounding worse but by the forms constructer do you mean when the object sender is or where do you mean

Comment: @JamesAdegoroye see my edit, I suppose your form class named `Form1`. That's how I mean. However if you open the Image via `OpenFileDialog`, you can just update the `originalImage` there. I hope you understand it.

Comment: Oh right thanks for that haha sorry for being a pain

Comment: I will i just not currently at my desktop now